# Laravel get url for file in public folder from full path

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel I save an uploaded folder in a directory in my public folder. I want to find a way to get the public url of this file from the file object itself.

E.g. `$file` is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`. So can do `$file->getRealPath()` which returns something like `C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\public\uploads\2015\2\test.pdf`.

How can I generate the public url for this? I tried using `asset($file->getRealPath());` but this gives something like `http://localhost/myapp/C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\public\uploads\2015\2\06-12-2014-2.pdf`. I.e. I need to remove the part of the path before the public folder before feeding it to `asset()`.

I thought of doing something like

```
asset(str_replace(public_path(), '' , $file->getRealPath()));
```

(which works, and should continue to work between environments) but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides **helper** functions to generate urls. For instance, if $file holds the path of your file then you can simply use the `url()` function to generate the public url of this file.

```
url($file)
```

**More information:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking into this for you. The problem is that `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` is really just a wrapper for PHP SplFileInfo http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getlinktarget.php with some extra functions.

None of these functions will give you what you want.

Your solutions posted is the best option - although if you wanted to clean it up a little bit - [I would suggest putting it inside a custom `HTML` macro class and doing it this way](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros):

```
HTML::macro('show_relative_path', function()
{
    return str_replace(public_path(), '' , $path);
});
```

Then in your view just do

```
asset(HTML::show_relative_path($file->getRealPath()));
```